# How can i set premissions in logon script?

Tags: logon-scripts

I created a logon script which mounts a few network drives on each user account.

---

My question is how could i permit it that when i **want the give one Special user the permission to get a Network drive but other users shouldn't have the permission to get that drive**.

---

I would also like to get that all into one logon-script.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your script and config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a logon script which only mounts a few Network drives on the user accounts in my Domain. I just want to know how can i set a permission for example  to the admin to get another Network drive which other users shouldn't be able to see.

Comment: Repeating the same thing as you wrote in your question doesn't help. We need to know more about your system in order to help you, and you need to do some basic legwork first. At this point we don't even know which operating system you are using, or how the network drives are accessed. There is no way for anyone to help you unless you add some hard information here.

Comment: The Thing i was lookin for is called acces based enumeration...  but i already solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* set permissions in a login script. Login scripts run in the context of the currently logged in user (there's a clue in the name) and unless your system is horribly broken you cannot grant yourself permissions to something you don't *already*  have permission to access.

I hope that what you're actually after is only mounting a drive for a user that already has permissions to access it and this should be possible with a bit of experimentation. The exact syntax and effort need will depend on your platform, and depending on what that is, login scripts might not be the best way of doing this; in Windows I would use GPOs to share drives based on whether or not the user has permission to do so, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your amswer rob. I solved my problem and the thing i was looking for is called acces based enumeration.